# 500 Internal Server Error when running through ajax jquery

Tags: html

500 Internal Server Error

## Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.
Please contact the server administrator
 and inform them of the time the error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.
Apache Server at app.gtechinfo.com Port 80

Comment: Can you post that error log?

Comment: Response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator
 and inform them of the time the error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at app.gtechinfo.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

your page that your ajax is trying  to post data too could have a syntax error check and see  could be missing a closing bracket or  a ;  check your server code

Comment: If your using wamp click on it click on apache and then click apache access log.  Scroll to the bottom. Your error will be displayed there

Comment: Try directly running your server  file  that your calling in your ajax method